# Cordova/Phonegap moveTo not getting root directory

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

This is an onSuccess function which is being called but the `moveTo` method is not giving the desired effect. It should move my image to file:///storage/sdcard0/PhotoscanPhotos/ but the debugging alert just shows `//PhotoscanPhotos`.

```
function movePhoto(fileEntry) {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function(fileSys) { //onsuccess
                fileSys.root.getDirectory("PhotoscanPhotos", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dir) {
                    var guid = guidGenerator();
                    Speicher.setPhotoFolder(dir.fullPath);
                    alert(dir.fullPath); //debugging
                    fileEntry.moveTo(dir, (guid + "foto.jpg"), onMoveSuccess, onFail);
                }, onFail);
            }, onFail);
    }
```

Anyone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong? It's a virtual copy from the Phonegap 3.1 API docs. I definitely have my config file correct.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Rest of Code for completeness:

```
function takePicture() {
        var code = $("#txtCode").val();
        if(!code){
            alert("Zuerst EAN-Code scannen oder eingeben.");
            return false;
        }else{
            ean = code;
        }
        navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail,
            { quality: 100, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
        return true;
    }

    function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
        createFileEntry(imageURI);
        showImageList();
    }

    function createFileEntry(imageURI) {
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, movePhoto, onFail);
    }



    function movePhoto(fileEntry) {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function(fileSys) { //onsuccess
                fileSys.root.getDirectory("PhotoscanPhotos", {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(dir) {
                    var guid = guidGenerator();
                    Speicher.setPhotoFolder(dir.fullPath);
                    alert(dir.fullPath); //debugging
                    fileEntry.moveTo(dir, (guid + "foto.jpg"), onMoveSuccess, onFail);
                }, onFail);
            }, onFail);
    }

    function onMoveSuccess(entry) {
        var image = {ean:ean, image: entry.fullPath, timestamp:convertDateToUTC()};
        alert(image.image); //debugging
        getPhotoFolder();
        alert(numOfPhotosStored + " photos stored"); //debugging
        images.push(image);
        Speicher.setImages(images);
        showImageList();
    }

    function onFail(error) {
        alert(error.code + error.message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, Phonegap updated the `fileTransfer` method 14 hours ago...

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/file_transfer_plugin_updated_to_0_4_2_on_phonegap_build

Two hours of my life I'll never get back. What I neglected to mention that this was working fine yesterday and I spent the last two hours checking versions for differences and finding none and tearing my hair out.